# Calculate least squares in batches

Tags: machine-learning, out-of-memory, linear-algebra, batch-processing, cupy

I want to calculate a Gaussian process. For this I need to calculate the following equation:
f = X @ Z^-1 @ y

To handle the inverse I use c = Z^-1 @ y which is the solution of the problem Z @ c = y. So, I use a solver for linear systems (least squares) to calculate c on my GPU (using cupy).
The problem now is, that I reach the memory capacity (16000x16000 matrix). Is it possible to calculate c in batches? Or how can I solve the out of memory issue?

I searched the internet but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The GPU will help you with the arithmetic, but will penalize data access.

Solving a linear system will require `O(n^2)` arithmetic operations, and the amount of data accessed is `O(n^2)`. So you are probably not going to have a big gain.

You will find efficient linear solvers CPU implementations in [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.solve.html), or [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) for instance, if you can use `float32` instead of `float64` even better.

You can have a matrix of 16000 x 16000 if you have a recent decent GPU, it would take 2GB using `float64` elements. Make sure to release all other allocated memory before trying to allocate `Z`, and when solving try not to allocate more data.
If the matrix is well conditioned, on GPU you could try to use `float16` that would place a 16000 x 16000 matrix in 512MB memory.

If you want to use GPU pytorch is my preferred option, and if you have an algorithm running on CPU you can run it on GPU with very little changes.